# GWT - NotificationMole not dissapearing

Tags: gwt, toast

I'm trying to implement a notification system in my GWT app
like this one: http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html

I found a GWT widget called NotificationMole, I succeeded on showing it in my page with this code:

```
toast = new NotificationMole();
toast.setAnimationDuration(2000);
bodyContainer.add(toast);
toast.show(event.getMessage());
```

I was expecting the notification to disappear after 2000 ms with the `setAnimationDuration(2000)` but it's not disappearing at all and I can't find any documentation on it either...

Comment: Taking a guess, can you set `setAnimationDuration(2000)` after the `show()` method - does that make a difference?

Comment: Going through the `GWT` documentation, `hideNow()` method can be used after the delay that you require programatically? Can't we? http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/NotificationMole.html#hideNow()

Comment: @BPavanKumar I tried that already, and it's not working. Thx though for trying to help. The second solution is what I temporarily did but I'm surprised that it's not doing it automatically ... A toast is supposed to always disappear ...

Comment: Cool, let me get back to you if I find a solution!